# React Native: why are useState hooks sometimes undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

In my React Native app I have two components, `A` and `B`:

```
export const A = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  return (
    <View>
      <B
        _text={text}
        _setText={setText}
      />
    </View>
  )
}

const B = ({_text, _setText}) => {
  console log(_text, _setText);
  ...
  ...
}
```

I console.log `_text` and `_setText` in `B`. This console.log gets called multiple times whenever I open the `B` component, and sometimes it logs both `_text` and `_setText` as `undefined`.

Does anyone know why this would be?

Comment: It might be because the data it's not there yet. you could try if(_text){console.log(_text);} Does it appears as undefined after that?

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely rendering the `B` Component before the text state is updated. To fix it, check that it isn't null/empty:

```
export const A = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  return (
    <View>
      {text ? <B
        _text={text}
        _setText={setText}
      /> : null}
    </View>
  )
}
```